# Reading from UART1 on BeagleBone Black: why the reversed byte order?

Tags: embedded-linux, reverse, endianness, uart, beagleboneblack

I want to read multiple-bytes-long data at once from UART1 / ttyO1 on BeagleBone Black (Debian) with the `read(2)` function (see my [former Q here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58650544/beaglebone-black-uart-software-fifo-size)). E.g.:

```
uint32_t _integer32;
read(_fd_rx, &_integer32, 4u);
```

But the destination variable `_integer32` will hold the received data bytes in reversed order. E.g. when the incoming bytes are coming in the order `0x01`, `0x02`, `0x03`, `0x04` then `_integer32` will hold the value: `0x04030201` instead of `0x01020304`.

Why is this happening?

The order of incoming bytes is surely right since

- multiple one-byte-long readings `read(_fd_rx, &_integer8, 1u);` (and printings) showed that the incoming order is correct, and
- I am the one who sends the data to the BBB with a USB-TTL converter cable.

I can imagine that ttyO1 is represented as a FIFO which is filled up correctly, only the `read()` doesn't act accordingly.

My goal would be to be able to read maybe even 4k (aka. N_TTY_BUF_SIZE) bytes at once with `read()` into a preallocated memory area. The required size is not foreknown.

Comment: "Why is this happening?" -- Because you are using an integer instead of an unsigned byte array. Your ARM processor is **little endian**, and an integer word fetched from memory reorders the bytes. If you fetch just a byte at a time from memory, then the bytes will be in order as expected.

Comment: @sawdust Thanks! I edited to make clear that `_integer32` is unsigned. But it is indeed an integer, not a byte array.

Comment: Are you saying that the _type of the pointer_ used as the 2nd parameter makes the difference in the reading? Or it is the number of required bytes (3rd param) that makes the difference?

Comment: Neither.  The **read()** syscall will copy the bytes in the proper/expected order into your buffer.  But whenever your program accesses that data as an integer, the CPU 'load int from memory' operation performs the little endian reordering of bytes.  (That's why I used "fetched from memory" rather than "read".) Prove it to yourself: create a union of an integer and a 4-byte array; then print out all values.  You get same byte data, but different byte order.